# Virtual inheritance from a namespaced Baseclass with private members fromt he namespace

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces

Why does the following code sample fail?

```
namespace Base {
    class Base {
        protected:
            int x;
    };

    class BaseAlt {
    };
}

namespace Derived {
    class Derived : public virtual Base::Base {
        private:
            Base::BaseAlt baseAlt;
    };
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

g++ compilation fails with the following error

```
error: ‘BaseAlt’ in ‘class Base::Base’ does not name a type
             Base::BaseAlt baseAlt;
```

Why though?

Comment: Your names clash, the moment you do `Base::BaseAlt` the compiler picks the class name `Base`.

Comment: try ::Base::BaseAlt baseAlt;

Comment: Thanks, that work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is resolving to the parent class "Base::Base" which does not have an internal class named BaseAlt. The fully qualified name of the class BaseAlt is "::Base::BaseAlt." The additional "::" are required to differentiate between the namespace and the class.